# Using Python 3 "requests" package to access web server with IP V6 address: works with W10, not with Rasberry Pi OS

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, ipv6, raspberry-pi4

We have a device currently under development that we want to test for different features and protocols. One of the features is this device has an embedded HTTP(S) server and we want to perform regression testing when we make changes in the device source code. for that purpose we use Jenkins and a Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB) as slave with PyTest as test framework, although our development environment is done with Windows 10.

We noticed a problem: when trying to connect to the device HTTP server with the IP V6 address on the RPi, we get a "[Errno 22] Invalid argument" error.

We reduced the test to a minimal Python 3 script to no avail: the same script works on Windows 10 but not on RPi.

Here is the script:

```
import os
import requests

ipv6_address = 'fe80::211:ff:fe4c:e565'

os.environ['no_proxy'] = 'localhost,foobar.com,192.168.10.*,{},[{}]'.format(ipv6_address, ipv6_address)

r = requests.get('https://[{}]/'.format(ipv6_address), verify=False, timeout=5)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
print(r.url)
```

Here are the results for Windows 10 (version 2004 19041.867):

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.7

$ python ~/test_req.py
C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1020: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'fe80::211:ff:fe4c:e565'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
200
{'Server': '', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Keep-Alive': '', 'Persist': '', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': '1429', 'Last-Modified': 'FRI JUL 07 16:43:06 2017', 'Etag': '"21D47F50-00000595-595FBA1A"'}
https://[fe80::211:ff:fe4c:e565]/
```

Result for Raspberry Pi (Linux raspberrypi 5.4.83-v7l-ALADDIN+ #1 SMP Tue Feb 9 14:23:45 CET 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux) :
[NOTE: *we have compiled a specific version of Linux for the Ixxat SocketCAN driver from the default kernel configuration, except the name*]

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3

$ python3 ~/test_req.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6369c30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fe80::211:ff:fe4c:e565', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6369c30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test_req.py", line 9, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://[{}]/'.format(ipv6_address), verify=False, timeout=5)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fe80::211:ff:fe4c:e565', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6369c30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'))
```

We would like to know whether someone has an idea of the source of this "invalid argument" error.